# Java Math.IEEERemainder confusing result

Tags: java, math, standards, ieee-754

Java's [Math.IEEERemainder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#IEEEremainder(double,%20double)) function states:

> The remainder value is mathematically equal to f1 - f2 × n, where n is
>   the mathematical integer closest to the exact mathematical value of
>   the quotient f1/f2, and if two mathematical integers are equally close
>   to f1/f2, then n is the integer that is even

For the following:

```
double f1 = 0.1;
double f2 = 0.04;
System.out.println(Math.IEEEremainder(f1, f2));
```

The output is `-0.019999999999999997`
However, `0.1/0.04 = 2.5` which is equidistant from both the integers `2` and `3`. Shouldn't we pick `n = 2` here, resulting in `0.1 - 0.04*2 = 0.02`, instead of `-0.02` ?

Comment: You can check the implementation of it in native c doe in open jdk source https://github.com/netroby/jdk9-dev/blob/master/jdk/src/java.base/share/native/libfdlibm/e_remainder.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

You would think that `0.1 / 0.04` would return exactly `2.5`, but that's not true. According to [this article](https://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/), `0.1` cannot be accurately represented using IEEE 754, and is actually represented as `0.100000000000000005551...`.

In this case, the quotient is *slightly* higher due to that minuscule offset, which results in a value of `3` for `n`, as it's no longer equidistant between `2` and `3`.

Computing it results in the following:

```
0.1 - 0.04 * 3 = 0.1 - 0.12 = -0.02 ~= -0.019999999999999997
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob ! That does make sense. Do you have any suggestions on what I could use to implement this standard ? BigDecimals ? Using `setScale()` to limit the number of decimal digits ?

Comment: `BigDecimal` will retain the precision and fix your problem; I'm sure you can figure it out :)

Comment: Thanks ! However, `((3 - (0.1 / 0.04)) == ((0.1 / 0.04) - 2))` evaluates to `true`, and both  `((3 - (0.1 / 0.04)) < ((0.1 / 0.04) - 2))` and  `((3 - (0.1 / 0.04)) >((0.1 / 0.04) - 2))` evaluate to `false`. I find this surprising, since this comparison evaluates 2.5 to be equidistant from both 2 and 3

Comment: Does this mean the Math.IEEEremainder() implementation is broken ?

Comment: No, it works exactly as specified, as some IEEE 754 floating points cannot be accurately represented with two's complement binary.

Comment: But then why does the evaluation I posted earlier, imply 2.5 to be equidistant from both 2 and 3 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173419/discussion-between-user1925405-and-jacob-g).